# /etc/pam.d configuration Ubuntu - common-* versus sytem-auth

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, pam

I'm trying to configure `/etc/pam.d` files on Ubuntu servers. I've already configured by RHEL servers by using the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.

**Problem:** `Could not chdir to home directory`
I believe this is because I haven't configured the right `common-*` file, however,
is it possible to use `system-auth` ([system-auth(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/system-auth)) in Ubuntu aswell for all of my settings instead of `/etc/pam.d/common-*`?
I'm not using the `pam-auth-update` command.